# Angular 2 - Is it possible to add a command for when a file is saved

Tags: node.js, angular, sass, scss-lint

I'm trying to setup SCSS-lint onto a Angular 2 project and although I can get it to work on npm start and if I ran my command manually, I can not figure out how to get it to run for when I save a file.

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run scss-lint && ng serve --host $npm_package_config_host --port $npm_package_config_port --ec=true",
    "start-live-data": "ng serve --host $npm_package_config_host --port $npm_package_config_port --environment=livedata --ec=true --aot",
    "start-prod": "npm run build-prod && npm run pm2:restart-prod || npm run pm2:start-prod",
    "start-prod-v2": "npm run build-prod && npm run pm2:restart-prod-v2 || npm run pm2:start-prod-v2",
    "build": "ng build --aot",
    "prebuild-prod": "npm install",
    "build-prod": "ng build --environment=production --aot",
    "test": "ng test -sm=false --code-coverage --single-run",
    "test-watch": "ng test --code-coverage",
    "test-debug": "ng test --browsers ChromeDebug",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "scss-lint": "sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "pm2:restart-prod": "NODE_ENV=production pm2 restart audience-dashboard-client",
    "pm2:start-prod": "NODE_ENV=production pm2 start -i max --name audience-dashboard-client node -- server.js",
    "pm2:restart-prod-v2": "NODE_ENV=production PORT=8085 pm2 restart audience-client-2",
    "pm2:start-prod-v2": "NODE_ENV=production PORT=8085 pm2 start --name audience-client-2 node -- server.js"
  }
```

> npm run scss-lint
>   The above command is the one that I'd like to run when the SCSS files are saved.

Has anyone experienced this problem before?

****** Update ******

The watch appears to be happening through ng serve and is it possible to add to this command?

Comment: Love how you get down voted and no explanation to why... If there is something wrong with my question then explain why and I'll happily change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. First install "watch" package:

```
npm install watch
```

Then in your package.json add in your scripts:

```
"scss:compiler": "./node_modules/.bin/watch \"sass-lint 'src/**/*.scss' -v -q\" src"
```

src should be the name of the folder you want to watch for changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll give this a go.

Comment: Hmm not sure why but this didn't work for me. I've updated my question with a bit more info

Comment: Did you try to run ng serve once the watch has triggered the task?